# Firebase Geopoint Issue

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

i have an issue when i store data in firebase as Dcoument when I use Geopoint.
I was creating an app with ionic, angular and firebase
I'm using the sintax:

```
new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
```

This reference is provided by Firebase. The problem is when i save the data. In some documents the saved data is like a map(number) [_lat: 33.3755692, _lng: 70.5231211], and in others documents is a firebase GeoPoint like this [33.3755692° S, 70.5231211° W]
I have the same reference to save the data in anothers collections and its work like spectet

I don't know why the same sentence create a diferents objects.

thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. I' ve using the NavigationExtras function to pass data to another page. I don't know why when i use this, the data change to an object {_lat:0000, _lng: 0000 }. So I avoid to use the navigationExtras an only send the data to firebase to keep the type like Geopoint. So the constructor new geoPoint is not the problem.